# How to find PSNR from two images with different size in python

Tags: image-processing, python, reconstruction, perceived-quality

I have 2 images, one original and other is reconstructed from the original via some processing. I want to find the PSNR for the reconstructed image The original has a size of `(180, 180)` but the reconstructed image has size of `(71,81)`. I am using cv2.reshape() to reshape the reconstructed image.

```
shape = 180
reconstructed = cv2.resize(reconstructed, (shape,shape))
reconstructed = cv2.normalize(reconstructed, None, alpha=0, beta = 255, norm_type= cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
original = cv2.normalize(original, None, alpha=0, beta = 255, norm_type= cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
MSE = np.mean((original - reconstructed)**2)
PSNR = 10*np.log10(255**2/MSE)
print(PSNR)
```

Since the sizes do not match and I have to calculate PSNR, I'm afraid that there might be some alignment issues and thus it may give wrong PSNR. What can be done to do calculate the PSNR accurately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your resizing method generates an additive pixel distortion, so that the MSE of two operations is the sum of the MSE of the individual operations.

You can get `MSE(reconstruction) + MSE(resizing from construction shape to original shape)`, by resizing the reconstructed image to the original shape. You can also get `MSE(reconstrution) + MSE(resizing from construction shape to original shape)` by resizing the original to the reconstruction shape.

```
shape = 180
r1 = cv2.resize(reconstructed, original.shape)
r2 = cv2.resize(original, reconstructed.shape)
r3 = cv2.resize(r2, original.shape)
r2 = cv2.normalize(r2, ...)
r1 = cv2.normalize(r1, ...)
original = cv2.normalize(original, ...)
# resizing original -> reconstructed.shape -> original.shape
m1 = mse(original, r3) 
# resizing original -> reconstructed.shape
m2 = mse(reconstructed, r2) 
# resizing reconstruction -> original.shape
m3 = mse(r1, original)

reconstrucion_MSE = ((m2 + m3) - m1) / 2
```

Using a weaker assumption, that the distortion on two operations is less than the sum of the distortions (something like the triangle inequality). Then instead of an exact value one would have three upper bounds bounds: `m1`, `m2`, and `((m2 + m3) - m1) / 2`, you can pick the minimum of them as an approximation to `reconstruction_MSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Image scaling can vary somewhat in terms of spatial phase, or how the (re-)sampling grid is overlaid the input grid.

Depending on how distorted your processing branch is, I would generate a «ping» image consisting of all (0,0,0), and one single pixel (255,255,255). Rund this through your processing and see how it aligns (eg plot a vertical and a horizontal section through its middle)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PSNR is a measure of how good was the reconstruction (For real world images it is a bad choice), you may choose a different approach which is dimensions insensitive.

On your original images, train an convolutional Auto Encoder. If your images are really world, you may use pre trained models.
Use the bottleneck of the Auto Encoder as an embedding. The dimensions of those embedding are pre defined by the net architecture and not by the input size.

[image]

**Remark**: Image from [Mathias Gronne - Into Image Embedding and Latent Spaces](https://towardsdatascience.com/0-6-5c5d9a18fcaa).

Now you have 2 options:

1. Measure the distance between the images in the latent space (Embedding).
2. Reconstruct using the decoder and compare same resolution image.

If your images are real world images, you have such encoders pre trained.
In case your images are not, you will have to train a model on your own. Which means you need to be able to generate a relatively large amount of data (Though augmentation and transfer learning can assist reducing that).